How can I copy API connections from my original resource group to another backup resource group Azure?
I'm trying to copy API connections from my source resource group to another resource group to serve a backup RG. The code I'm currently using is moving the API connection to another RG, so the target RG is not serving its purpose as a backup RG. I slightly modified the code to process 20 API connections since I'm managing around 200+ API connection at the moment.
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient

# Define your subscription ID and resource group names
subscription_id = [REDACTED]
tenant_id = [REDACTED]
client_id = [REDACTED]
client_secret = [REDACTED]

# Authenticate using Azure Identity
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

# Resource groups
# API Connections must be retained in source_api
resource_group_name_source = "azdnaeurgrgp1dev_source_api" 
resource_group_name_target = "azmgmteurgrgp_backup_api"

# Get all resources in the source resource group
resources = list(resource_client.resources.list_by_resource_group(
    resource_group_name_source, 
    filter="resourceType eq 'Microsoft.Web/connections'"
))

# Debug: Print the resources retrieved
for resource in resources:
    print(resource.id)

# Prepare the target resource group ID
target_resource_group_id = f"/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group_name_target}"

# Move resources in batches of 20
for i in range(0, len(resources), 20):
    batch_resources = resources[i:i+20]
    resource_ids = [resource.id for resource in batch_resources]

    # Move resources to the target resource group
    move_resources_poller = resource_client.resources.begin_move_resources(
        resource_group_name_source,
        {
            "targetResourceGroup": target_resource_group_id,
            "resources": resource_ids
        }
    )

    # Wait for the move operation to complete
    move_resources_poller.result()

    print(f"Moved {len(resource_ids)} resources.")

print("All resources moved successfully to", resource_group_name_target)


Ideally I was hoping for API connections to be copied instead of being moved. I tried to use chat GPT for code to be tweak but its only suggesting again to use update
